# Display box from object on canvas

Tags: javascript, object, canvas

I tried to draw 2 boxes an a canvas,but I cant see anything. Does anyone has an Idea?

```
var arena = {
o1: ['gate',5,5,20,20],
o2: ['block',50,40,30,40]
};

$(document).ready(function(){
var c = document.getElementById('canvas.arena');
var canvas=c.getContext("2d");

canvas.lineWidth="6";
canvas.strokeStyle="red";

var xpercent = c.width/100;
var ypercent = c.height/100;

for (var key in arena) {
    canvas.beginPath();
    canvas.rect(arena[key][1]*xpercent, arena[key][2]*ypercent, arena[key][3]*xpercent, arena[key][4]*ypercent);
}
});
```

Comment: So read carefully **getElementById**... and you use what selector?

Comment: unless that element's name is actually "canvas.arena" i guess....

Answer (score 0):

- If your element ID is `id="canvas"` than use `getElementById("canvas")`
- Use `ctx` as a shorthand for CanvasRendering**Context** (not `canvas`)
- Use `ctx.fill()`

```js
var arena = {
  o1: ['gate', 5, 5, 20, 20],
  o2: ['block', 50, 40, 30, 40]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  ctx.lineWidth = "6";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

  var xpercent = c.width / 100;
  var ypercent = c.height / 100;

  for (var key in arena) {
    var arr = arena[key];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(arr[1] * xpercent, arr[2] * ypercent, arr[3] * xpercent, arr[4] * ypercent);
    ctx.fill();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```